# React-Native google Map

Tags: android, react-native

I want to display a Google Map in React Native, and I've set up all the necessary configurations, permissions, and API registration, but I'm only seeing the Google logo icon, and the map is not showing. Can you help me understand why this is happening?

I want to show google map in my rn app.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on these links to learn how to use a Google Map with React Native.

Solution 1 :
[React-native-maps Blank page Only google logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642328/react-native-maps-blank-page-only-google-logo)

Solution 2 :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzjWv1X-uyg

Solution 3 :
https://www.oneclickitsolution.com/blog/integrate-google-maps-in-react-native/

Solution 4 :
https://aboutreact.com/react-native-map-example/

Solution 5 :
check out the permission which map uses in androidManifest.xml

```
<permission android:name="com.shop.shoppinglist.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
 android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.shop.addtask.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```